# Setting up a UITableView inside View Controller Programatically

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios5, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have setup a UITableView controller within my view controller as follows:

```
fieldView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, logoView.bounds.size.height, 320, (screen.size.height - logoView.bounds.size.height)) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
[fieldView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
fieldView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

The view controller is setup to be a TableViewDelegate as follows:

```
 UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource...
```

Question: What do I need to do to the table view delegate methods for them to control this added sub view?

```
#pragma mark - 
#pragma Table View Delegate Methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    NSLog(@"Here");
    return 1;
}
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)fieldView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSString *sectionName;
    NSLog(@"Here2");
```

The above methods are in the view controller but not called?

Comment: `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` is there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need:

```
// Add these right after creating the UITableView
fieldView.delegate = self;
fieldView.dataSource = self;

// don't forget to add the tableview
[self.view addSubview:fieldView];
```

You also need all of the basic `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` methods. It's exactly the same as if you had implemented a `UITableViewController`. At a minimum you need:

```
tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

If you plan to support table editing there are additional methods you must implement and override.

Comment: Thanks, I have the other methods just missed the setting of delegate and dataSource.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the delegate & data source for the table view.

```
fieldView.delegate = controller; // self, if you are creating this table inside your controller
```